# Is it possible to import roles into an ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible

I have a bunch of playbooks where a big percentage of roles are common to all servers. So I'd like to do something like:

```
    --- 
    - hosts: nfs2pre2
      sudo: true
      gather_facts: no
      roles:
        - include: initial_setup.yml
        - { role: role10, tags: ['role10' ] }
        - { role: role11, tags: ['role11' ] }
```

The `initial_setup.yml` would be something like:

```
     - { role: role1, tags: ['role1' ] }
     - { role: role2, tags: ['role2' ] }
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Why don't you try that and tell us...

Comment: I already tried but none of my tests worked

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible as far as I know, but there is a simple workaround. You can create a role which will only have dependencies on other roles. To follow your example, you can create a role `initial_setup`, by creating a directory `roles/initial_setup` and in it create a directory `meta` with a file `main.yml`:

```
# roles/initial_setup/meta/main.yml
---
dependencies:
  - { role: 'role1', tags: 'role1' }
  - { role: 'role2', tags: 'role2' }
```

Now you can use `initial_setup` as any regular role:

```
- hosts: nfs2pre2
  sudo: true
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
    - { role: initial_setup, tags: ['initial_setup' ] }
    - { role: role10, tags: ['role10' ] }
    - { role: role11, tags: ['role11' ] }
```